# For prototype.js why I can't see the debug information of onSuccess in the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototypejs

I'm using the `Ajax.Request` in prototype.js(1.6) like this:

```
    new Ajax.Request(URL, {method: "get",
        onSuccess: cbFn,
        onCreate: function(req) {
            $("fetchBtn").value = "Fetching..."

        },
        onFailure: function(req){
            console.log(req)
            alert("nima")
        },
        parameters: {"id": pmid}});
```

however there is a bug in `cbFn`, and when `cbFn` is called by `Ajax.Request`, it just stops in the statement which has bugs. However, it just stops silently that I can not see the error information  in Firebug. I also tried `onFailure`, but it seems that it is not even `called` when `onSuccess` is failed.

Does anyone have ideas about how to check the debug information of `cbFn` function? Thanks!

Comment: Also the latest version of PrototypeJS is 1.7.1 please try and upgrade if you are able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw you have been use jquery in your java script. In that case, you can using the jquery ajax GET/POST to solve your problem with effiency.
Some thing like that:

```
jqxhr = $.get("example.php", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.done(function() { alert("second success"); })
.fail(function() { alert("error"); })
.always(function() { alert("finished"); });
```

jquery do better in multiple browser for you